# las consultas no se ejecutan en otros equipos

Tags: mysql, xampp, localhost

lo que me pasa es lo siguiente, tengo unos sensores conectados a una base de datos la cual se muestra a través de unos medidores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ok, hasta ahí todo bien, en el localhost los datos cargan bien todo va de maravilla pero cuando accedo a el servidor por la ip desde otro equipo aparecen los medidores pero no cargan los datos, no se que podría estar fallando, este es el código que llama los datos por si acaso

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=iot;host=127.0.0.1","root","");
switch($_GET['q']){
        // Buscar Último Dato
        case 1:
            $statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT Temp_Datos_A, Temp_Datos_O FROM datos ORDER BY Id_Datos DESC LIMIT 0,1");
            $statement->execute();
            $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $json=json_encode($results);
            echo $json;
        break;
        // Buscar Todos los datos
        default:

            $statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT Temp_Datos_A, Temp_Datos_O FROM datos ORDER BY Id_Datos ASC");
            $statement->execute();
            $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $json=json_encode($results);
            echo $json;
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: https://www.gestionatuweb.net/acceder-a-xampp-desde-otros-dispositivos-en-tu-red-local-explicacion-en-linux-y-windows/ espero esto te sirva

Comment: Pero con esto `host=127.0.0.1` estas indicando solo acceso a nivel de localhost, pero si tratas de acceder desde un equipo remoto no debería ir una IP?, me parece el servidor donde esta XAMPP debe tener una IP asignada y entonces los equipos traten de acceder a ella

Comment: no es eso amigo, quizá no me di a entender, si tengo acceso al servidor pero desde otros equipos no me muestra los datos de la base de datos

Comment: si eso como hago eso ?

Answer (score 1):

No puedo comentar pero espero ayudarte. no entendi bien como era el problema pero  necesitas darle privilegios a la red que entrara a usar tu localhost.
Segun entendi aun estas trabajando con localhost, entonces:

1. Entras a  localhost/phpmyadmin
2. Seleccionas tu base de datos
3. En las opciones de arriba selecciona la que dice privilegios
4. Agregar cuenta de usuario
5. Pon todos los datos, Host(la red con la que entraras para probar), (no pongas contraseña por si batallas al ponerla)  y le das todos los privilegios globales y listo.

Comment: ya lo hice y en sigue igual el localhost sale pero en otros no

Comment: pero haber ya que puedo comentar mi pregunta xD, me puedes platicar como lo quieres hacer, tienes el servidor corriendo en localhost? si es asi , cuando entras en otras computadoras tienes el servidor corriendo?

Comment: si, el servidor esta en localhost, y si anda bien desde otros equipos me aparece solo los medidores, como que no esta leyendo los datos de la base de datos

Comment: ok, ya revise coloque una tabla y si puedo leer la base de datos desde otros equipos, el problema esta en donde se convierte a json o algo así, pero lo raro es que en el localhost funciona perfectamente pero en remoto no

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: ya lo resolví  .

Comment: @brian-02 si lo resolviste podrias agregar una respuesta acorde a lo que dice [answer]